# ¿Como generar una xml a partir de una dtd?

Tags: xml

He creado una dtd (la cual se muestra a continuacion) y necesito crear un xml a partir del documento dtd. Tengo algunas dudas acerca de ambas cosas. la primera pregunta seria ¿El documento dtd debe llevar encabezado tal cual lo puse o solamente el xml ya que en este caso la dtd es un documento aparte? la otra pregunta seria ¿En base a la dtd como quedaria el xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ELEMENT calendario (mes, dia, hora)>
<!ELEMENT mes (enero|febrero|marzo|abril|mayo|junio|julio|agosto|septiembre|octubre|noviembre|diciembre>

<!ELEMENT enero (31)>
<!ELEMENT febrero (28|29)>
<!ELEMENT marzo (31)>
<!ELEMENT abril (30)>
<!ELEMENT mayo (31)>
<!ELEMENT junio (30)>
<!ELEMENT julio (31)>
<!ELEMENT agosto (30)>
<!ELEMENT septiembre (31)>
<!ELEMENT octubre (30)>
<!ELEMENT noviembre (31)>
<!ELEMENT diciembre (30)>

<!ELEMENT dia (lunes|martes|miercoles|jueves|viernes|sabado|domingo)>

<!ELEMENT lunes(11a12p|12p1p|1p2p|2p3p|3p4p|4p5p|5p6p|6p7p|7p8p|8p9p|9p10p)>
<!ELEMENT martes(11a12p|12p1p|1p2p|2p3p|3p4p|4p5p|5p6p|6p7p|7p8p|8p9p|9p10p)>
<!ELEMENT miercoles(11a12p|12p1p|1p2p|2p3p|3p4p|4p5p|5p6p|6p7p|7p8p|8p9p|9p10p)>
<!ELEMENT jueves(11a12p|12p1p|1p2p|2p3p|3p4p|4p5p|5p6p|6p7p|7p8p|8p9p|9p10p)>
<!ELEMENT viernes(11a12p|12p1p|1p2p|2p3p|3p4p|4p5p|5p6p|6p7p|7p8p|8p9p|9p10p)>
<!ELEMENT sabado(11a12p|12p1p|1p2p|2p3p|3p4p|4p5p|5p6p|6p7p|7p8p|8p9p|9p10p)>
<!ELEMENT domingo(11a12p|12p1p|1p2p|2p3p|3p4p|4p5p|5p6p|6p7p|7p8p|8p9p|9p10p)>

<!ELEMENT hora (disponible|ocupada)>
```

Answer (score 0):

para la primera pregunta en caso de que quieras hacer el DTD en un documento a parte, el DTD no va a llevar la primera línea, comenzará directamente con la tercera.
Y así a simple vista creo que va a quedar con este estilo:

```xml
<calendario>
  <mes></mes>
  <dia>
    <lunes></lunes>
  </dia>
  <hora></hora>
</calendario>
```

Aun faltarían los #PCDATA y demás.
Tengo un repositorio en GitHub por si te sirve de ayuda, https://github.com/alexbs01/XML/blob/master/DTD.md